# End to end testing sliders by putting a specific value in Protractor

Tags: angular, slider, protractor

I have some slider inputs in Angular 2 that I want to test using Protractor:

```
<input type="slider" min="0" max="100" ... />
```

I learned to perform drag and drop actions like this:

```
browser.actions().dragAndDrop(slider, {
    x: 30,
    y: 0
}).perform();

expect(... )
```

The problem is I want to be able to check if another value on the page has changed according to the new value of the slider. It seems like this technique of dragging the slider differs by screen size, so that the value I need to expect for will vary based on the system on which the test is run. Is there a better way to test dragging the slider?

Comment: did you try getting the value of that slider? that will exactly tell where you are? expect(slider.getAttribute('value')).toEqual('<your value>');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to ask:

First, is the slider itself a set size, or does it vary based on browser size? If it is a set size and does not scale, there shouldn't be any worry.

Second, do you want to set a specific browser size before the test starts to lock it to one result? If you can lock the browser size, you can always get the expected results

As an actual solution, this slider has values 0-100 only, right? You may consider getting the sliders width, then dragging it based on pixels calculated against that to achieve an overall % regardless of the size of the slider.

Edit: For setting browser size

`browser.manage().window().setSize(width, height);`

Comment: Correct, it's responsive. Locking the browser size would work.

Comment: I added an example of setting the browser size, in case you need it!